# if a function sequence converges a.e, then it uniformly converges a.e

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Assume $f,f_1,...,f_n,... :X\to\mathbb C$ are measureable functions, $f_j\overset{a.e}{\to}f$, and $X$ is $\sigma-$finite.

Then there are $\{E_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ such that $f_j\to f$ uniformly on $E_k$ for each $k\in\mathbb N$.

What I thought:
Take $A_k$ finite sets such that $X=\cup A_k$ and define $F_k=\cup_{j=1}^k A_k$.

Using Egorof's theorem, chose $E_k\subset F_k$ with $\mu(F_k\\E_k)<2^{-k}$ and $f_j\to f$ uniformly on $E_k$.

So I only get $\mu(X\\\cup E_k\leq\sum \mu (F_k\\E_k)=1$, but I can't get it to become $0$.

Thanks!

Comment: And another thought of mine: is that a much stronger form of Egorof? which is as far as I know not true -  Assume $X$ is finite, then we'd get $f_j\to f$ on $E\subset X$ with $m(E^c)=0$, meaning a.e convergece implies a.e uniform convergence.

Comment: The conclusion only implies that $f_n \to f$ uniformly on each set $E_k$ **seperately**. This means that the "speed of uniform convergence" can differ greatly between the individual $E_k$. For a different example, if $f:\Bbb{N}\to \Bbb{R}$ is a sequence of functions on the natural numbers which converges pointwise to $f$, then clearly $\Bbb{N}=\bigcup_k \{k\}$ and $f_n \to f$ uniformly on each set $\{k\}$, but this does not imply $f_n \to f$ uniformly on all of $n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your idea is essentially correct, with one additional twist:

For each $\ell,k$ choose $E_{k,\ell} \subset F_k$ with $\mu(F_k \setminus E_{k,\ell}) < 1/\ell$ and $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $E_{k,\ell}$. Now use all $(E_{k,\ell})_{k,\ell}$, which is still a countable family.

Also, as my answer here ([Measure Spaces: Uniform & Integral Convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1068043/measure-spaces-uniform-integral-convergence)) shows, you can in general **not** get $X = \bigcup_k A_k$, but only $\mu(X \setminus \bigcup_k A_k) = 0$.

To see $\mu( X \setminus \bigcup_{k,l} E_{k,l})=0$, convince yourself that

$$
X \setminus \bigcup_{k,l} E_{k,l} \subset \bigcup_k\bigg[ E_k \setminus \bigcup_l E_{k,l}\bigg],
$$
which is a countable union of nullsets.

Comment: Thanks. Could you elaborate on the reason that $\mu(X\\ \cup E_{k,l}=0$? and also if you will, respond to the comment above.

Comment: @MeasureTheory: Does my edit clarify things?