# Question on Egoroff-like theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, uniform-convergence

Hi all I was tackled by this question from Folland's real analysis second edition in the second chapter, it looks like a modified Egoroff theorem but I cannot really tackle it, it is question 41 of chapter 2 which reads as follows:

> Let $\mu$ be a $\sigma$-finite  measure and $ f_n \rightarrow f $ a.e. Then there exist measurable sets $E_1,E_2,\ldots \subset X $ such that 
>   $$\mu\left(\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty E_i\right)^C\right)=0$$ and $f_n \rightarrow f $ uniformly on each $ E_i. $

I think this might have something to do with Egoroff's theorem but that theorem mentions nothing about complement having measure zero, only as small as you would like, which is what confuses me. Can anyone point out a proof of this with an explanation?

Comment: The ideas in my answer here (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1068043/measure-spaces-uniform-integral-convergence) should be helpful.

Comment: @PhoemueX thanks tried your other answer but I still cannot understand it

Comment: If you start with the stronger assumption that $\mu$ is a finite measure, can you see how the assertion is obtained from Egorov's theorem?

Comment: @DanielFischer : maybe then I can take for all natural n's a set $ E_n $ whose complement is less then $ 1/n $  on which the convergence is uniform and then take the countable intersection of these sets? Does that work?

Comment: Why would you intersect?

Comment: @DanielFischer : because in Egoroff's theorem each set is guaranteed to have complement less than any number you might like (set depends on the number) so I cannot guarantee complement being of measure zero only from Egoroff's result

Comment: But you know that $\mu\biggl(X\setminus\bigcup E_n\biggr) = 0$, and that's what the assertion wants. So you can take the $E_n$ directly.

Comment: @DanielFischer : Ok got your point but why do I know that if $ \mu(E_n) <1/n $ then their union's complement is zero?

Comment: Let $F = \bigcup E_n$. Then you have $X\setminus F \subset X \setminus E_k$, and hence $\mu(X\setminus F) < 1/k$. Since that holds for all $k$, $\mu(X\setminus F) = 0$. Okay, the case of finite measure done. Now, for $\sigma$-finite measure, write $X = \bigcup A_m$, where each $A_m$ has finite measure. Perhaps it makes things easier to assume the $A_m$ disjoint, one can do that. So by the preceding, for each $m$, we have a sequence $E^{(m)}_n$ of subsets of $A_m$. How can you use that to get the desired sequence of subsets of $X$?

Comment: @DanielFischer : got it thanks

Comment: @AbeerAbassi: When you have got it worked out, you can post your own answer to this question, with your solution.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Thank you working on it currently

Answer (score 1):

Since $\mu$ is a $\sigma-$finite measure, there exists $\{A_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $\bigcup_{n}A_n=X$ and $\mu(A_n)<\infty$ $\forall n$.

Now, let $n\in \mathbb{Z}^+$ be given. Since $f_n\rightarrow f$ a.e. on $A_n$, by Egoroff's theorem, for any $k\in \mathbb{Z}^+$ there is $E_{n,k}\subset A_n$ such that $\mu(A_n\setminus E_{n,k})<\frac{1}{2^nk}$ and $f_n\rightarrow f$ uniformly on $E_{n,k}$.

Then observe that, for given $j\in \mathbb{Z}^+$,

\begin{align*}
\mu(\left(\bigcup_{n,k}E_{n,k}  \right)^c)&= \mu\left( \bigcup_{n} A_n \setminus \bigcup_{n,k} E_n  \right)\\ &= \mu\left(\bigcup_{n}\left(A_n\setminus \bigcup_{k} E_{n,k}\right)\right)\\&\leq \sum_n \mu\left(A_n\setminus \bigcup_k  E_n\right)\\&=\sum_n \mu\left(\bigcap_k\left( A_n\setminus E_{n,k} \right)  \right)\\& \leq \sum_n \mu(A_n\setminus E_{n,j})  \\&<\sum_n\frac{1}{2^nj}\\&<\frac{1}{j}.
\end{align*}

Since $j\in \mathbb{Z}^+$ is arbitrary, $\mu(\left(\bigcup_{n,k}E_{n,k}  \right)^c)=0$.

Since $f_n\rightarrow f$ uniformly on each $E_{n,k}$ by construction, $\{E_{n,k}\}_{n,k}$ is the countable  collection of the measurable subsets of $X$. Thus,  we are done.

Comment: Hi, when you write $\mu(E_n^c) < \frac{1}{n}$ you actually mean $\mu(A_n - E_n)$.  Thus your argument doesn't work as stated. But you can actually prove that Egoroff works for $\sigma- $ finite case by using your construction and using a standard $\frac{\epsilon}{2^n}$ argument.

Comment: @LucyferZedd  I did not realize that! I fixed it :) Thank you!

Comment: Are the $A_n$ should  be pairwise disjoint？

Comment: and when $\epsilon$ change $A_n$ change too..so  you can’t say $m((\bigcup E_n)^c)$=0...

Comment: @jackson  Thanks for commenting on my proof. My proof is still valid. Firstly, the definition of sigma finite measure does not require $A_n$ to be pairwise disjoint. And $\epsilon$ does not depend on $A_n$. Even we choose $A_n$ before saying $\epsilon$.

Comment: sorry I mean when $\epsilon $change,$\E_n$ change too

Comment: Sorry I mean when$\epsilon $changes,,$E_n$ changes too

Comment: @jackson  Thanks!  you are right.  I have corrected the answer. Sorry for late reply.

Comment: @LevBan actually i am working on a question more explicit can you go into my profile and help me about it

Comment: @LevBahn Though I would classify my real analysis skills as "bad, at best", I am not sure why this answer received a downvote.  My only question: what would happen if we DON'T switch from $k$ to $j$ (third line up in the equations)?  What breaks?