# A problem related to application of Egoroff theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\{ f_n \}$ be a sequence of measurable functions on $E$ that converges to the real-valued $f$ pointwise on $E$. Show that $E = \bigcup E_k$, where for each index $k$, $E_k$ is measurable, and $\{ f_n \}$ converges uniformly to $f$ on each $E_k$ if $k > 1$, and $m( E_1) = 0$.

my attempt: if $E$ has finite measure then we can apply Egoroff theorem, but how do we get set $E_1$ of measure exactly zero? next when $E$ has infinite measure then case is even more difficult is not it? need help.

Comment: Are these functions defined on the real line, not a general measure space? This will matter in the second part, I suspect, because given the first result, the second result follows from a "standard $\sigma$-finiteness argument". (The way this works is that you decompose the space into countably many finite measure subsets, conclude the result on each subset, and then (by some additional steps) conclude the result for the whole space.) I'm not so sure about even the first result, though: I agree that the condition $m(E_1)=0$ is harsh.

Comment: See the second part of my answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1068043/measure-spaces-uniform-integral-convergence